# Many to many with Hibernate and annotations for self referencing

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

My brain is starting to hurt thinking about this, is it as simple as:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "following", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> followers = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> following = new HashSet<User>();
```

Comment: @jenson-button-event do I have to specify linker table, can't I just let hibernate choose ?

Comment: you don't have to but its recommended - based on rarely do you not need other columns inbetween - but hey, here's how to do it, make sure you specify the table and columns http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: @jenson-button-event and you don't need mapped by on both sides

Comment: Also, `CascadeType.ALL` on many-to-many is a code smell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "following", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="UserRel", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ParentId")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="UserId")})
private Set<User> followers = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="UserRel", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="UserId")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ParentId")})
private Set<User> following = new HashSet<User>();
```

Comment: thanks, but I just removed mappedBy from one declaration and it works. You can't have mappedBy on both sides, so your exampke wouldn;t work

Comment: ok,  so its picking table and column names by convention...sweet

Comment: I think the `@JoinTable` on `followers` might fail with an error like: "Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn"