# Hibernate self referenced relation foreign key constraint problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am setting up a Springboot API which uses hibernate to communicate with the database. I have a User table, and each user should be able to follow other users. I am not experienced with hibernate, so after a while I got something that seemed to work, except that I cannot delete a user if that specific user is being followed by other user(s). This is because of a foreign key constraint.

This is what the user looks like:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true)
    @JsonProperty
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @JsonProperty
    private String email;

    @Column
    @JsonProperty
    private String hashedSaltedPassword;

    @Column
    @JsonProperty
    private String salt;

    @Column
    @JsonProperty
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    @JsonProperty
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Follows", schema = "todo", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
    private List<User> follows;
```

This creates the user table and a seperate table called User_Follows. This table has the user_id and a follows_id, which is the userId that is being followed. This is pretty much what I want.

Deleting a user works perfectly as long as that user isn't being followed by other users (so as long as the userId of that user isn't in the follows_id column).

But it gives the following error if it is:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FKc38v25qxktm9b0r7lg1s2t1tl". The conflict occurred in database "dbi390100_db", table "todo.User_Follows", column 'follows_id'.
```

This should not happen, what I want is that all rows where the userId exists of the User_Follows table will be deleted whenever the user is being deleted.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Not related to your question but usually the hashed/salted/password and salt should not leave the database. You might very quickly be showing password (albeit hashed) to users who should not be seing them, especially if your export them in JSON.

Comment: @Guillaume The password indeed doesn't leave the db, I just forgot to remove the JSON annotation, the salt however does, because it is needed to hash the password in the client-side for logging in.

Comment: I fixed the issue by executing this statement right before deleting the user: DELETE FROM [todo].[User_Follows] WHERE [todo].[User_Follows].[follows_id] = :id; This works, however I can't imagine that this is how you are supposed to use hibernate, so if anyone knows a clean solution, please post it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of accomplishing what you want.

- Define a `mappedBy` property with another field to let hibernate know about the entire relationship, something like:

```java
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "follows")
private List<User> followers = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708271/self-referencing-manytomany-with-hibernate-and-annotations)

- Or you can create a `@PreRemove` method in your user class to manually delete all references of your User:

```java
@PreRemove
private void removeFromFollowers() {
   for (User user : followers) {
       user.removeFollowed(this);
   }
}
```